# Why am I getting this big value at the end?

Tags: c++

I need to find the biggest value in an array, but instead I'm getting a huge number at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int masivs[5];
    int enter = 0;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter number:";
        std::cin >> enter;
        masivs[i] = enter;
        std::cout << masivs[i] << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "End filling array" << std::endl;

    int index = masivs[0];
         
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(index > masivs[i + 1]){
            index = index;
            std::cout << index << "\n";
        }else if (index < masivs[i + 1]){
            index = masivs[i + 1];
            std::cout << index << "\n";
        }else if(index == masivs[i + 1]){
            index = index;
            std::cout << index << "\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "End calculating" << "\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << index << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the image of output:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `masivs[i + 1]` when `i` is `4`?

Comment: Please avoid displaying output in images. They are a pain to read. Add the output as text in your question instead.

Comment: `index = index;` is also rather suspicious.  What do you expect that code to do?  Consider taking the time to learn how to run your code in a debugger.  Once you are runbning your code in a debugger, these tasks will become _significantly_ easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "off by one" error, because... You are off by one.

Usually, this error is caused due to confusion that array indexes start at 0, but in your case you just misjudged the loop counters:

```
if(index > masivs[i + 1])
```

also:

```
index = masivs[i + 1];
```

When `i` is 4, you are trying to access `masivs[5]` which is past your array memory.

But this is "C style" array, so C++ does not check its size, just reads whatever happens to be at that memory address.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot.

Comment: `"so C++ does not check its size, just reads whatever happens to be at that memory address"` -- Not necessarily. If a compiler can detect undefined behavior at compile-time, it may consider the code unreachable and optimize it away completely. See the following article for further information: [Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)